# JavaScript .forEach "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html

la función para ocultar el item me da problemas y no me deja ni enseñar el otro item. Si comento la función y todas las llamadas que le hago por lo menos me deja enseñar los otros items al darle al botón.

Dice ".forEach is not a function" pero ustedes pueden intentarlo y les saldrá lo mismo. Gracias por su ayuda.

```js
const buttonSlidePrev = document.getElementById("prev");
const buttonSlideNext = document.getElementById("next");
const images = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

let index = 0;
const total = images.length;
const mostrarItem = (index) =>{
    images[index].classList.add('item-active');
}
mostrarItem(index);


function ocultarItem(){
  images.forEach(item =>{
 item.classList.remove('item-active');
});
}


buttonSlideNext.addEventListener('click', e=>{
    if(index < total -1){
        index++;
        ocultarItem();
        mostrarItem(index);
    }
})

buttonSlidePrev.addEventListener('click', e=>{
 if(index > 0){
  index--;
ocultarItem();
mostrarItem(index);
  }
});
```

```css
.item-active{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
    <div id="slider-container" class="slider-container">
        <div id="buttons-container" class="buttons-container">
            <button id="prev" class="prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
            <button id="next" class="next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div id="slider-items" class="slider-items">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="../assets/images/fotoslider.png" alt="" class="image">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="../assets/images/fotoslider2.png" alt="" class="image">
            </div>
         <div class="item">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Has intentado mostrar que contiene la variable images usando console.log antes de llamar a forEach? Lo más seguro es que tenga una valor undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `forEach()` está disponible para [listas de nodos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList) que se obtienen por funciones como `querySelectorAll()`, sin embargo, estás usando `getElementsByClassName()`, que devuelve una [Colección HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) que es iterable, pero no dispone del método `forEach()`.

Para que tu *script* funcione, tienes tres opciones:

1. Asegurarte de obtener una lista de nodos, usando *querySelectorAll* para seleccionar todos los elementos con clase *item*:
   `const images = document.querySelectorAll(".item");`
2. "Convertir" la colección HTML en un arreglo:
   `Array.from(images)`
3. Usar otra estructura para iterar, como [`for(let item of images)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of)  o [`for(let index in images)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in)

En el fragmento de código usé la segunda opción, pero podría haber incompatibilidad en algunos navegadores; es cuestión de probar y elegir la que mejor te acomode.

```js
const buttonSlidePrev = document.getElementById("prev");
const buttonSlideNext = document.getElementById("next");
const images = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

let index = 0;
const total = images.length;
const mostrarItem = (index) =>{
    images[index].classList.add('item-active');
}
mostrarItem(index);


function ocultarItem(){
  Array.from(images).forEach(item =>{
 item.classList.remove('item-active');
});
}


buttonSlideNext.addEventListener('click', e=>{
    if(index < total -1){
        index++;
        ocultarItem();
        mostrarItem(index);
    }
})

buttonSlidePrev.addEventListener('click', e=>{
 if(index > 0){
  index--;
ocultarItem();
mostrarItem(index);
  }
});
```

```css
.item-active{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider-container" class="slider-container">
        <div id="buttons-container" class="buttons-container">
            <button id="prev" class="prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
            <button id="next" class="next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div id="slider-items" class="slider-items">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="../assets/images/fotoslider.png" alt="" class="image">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="../assets/images/fotoslider2.png" alt="" class="image">
            </div>
         <div class="item">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me funcionó. Es la segunda vez que tengo errores banales que al final me dañan todo. Me falta mucho por aprender, veo.